# Windows does not load, installed in a separated HHD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I have a laptop with two hard disks:

1. SSD with installed Ubuntu 16.04 in the standard disk slot
2. HHD with installed Windows 10 in the optical drive slot

When bot disks are present I can't boot windows. Also when I select ODD in the boot options at startup the system fall back to the SSD and Ubuntu is loaded.

If instead I physically remove the SSD from the laptop and I leave the HDD with windows in the optical drive slot, Windows loads normally.

How can I choose at startuo which OS use? Either by selecting the boot device or having them in grub choiches?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install grub 2 via a Ubuntu liveCD. Hope this will help. http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to go into your windows settings and disable fast boot.

Then, shut down windows fully and properly, do not hibernate.

Finally, boot up ubuntu and run the following command to update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```